# How do I enable multi-core option for training Stanford NER model?

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

Does Stanford crf classifier for NER support multi-core operations?

If yes, how do I enable it?

I have tried `nthreads` parameter, but it shows this:

> Unknown property: |nthreads|

Answer (score 2):

For multithreading during training, try the option -multiThreadGrad .
For multithreading during testing, try the option -multiThreadClassifier .

Answer (score -1):

Great question - I upvoted as I was in the same boat as you. Angel's answer helped me as well though partially. I had to dig into the code to figure out what it is and how to specify. Here's its key use:

```
new MulticoreWrapper<Pair<Integer, List<Integer>>, Pair<Integer, Double>>     (multiThreadGrad, (calculateEmpirical ? expectedAndEmpiricalThreadProcessor :   expectedThreadProcessor) )
```

And according to the `MulticoreWrapper` doc the first parameter:

> nThreads - If less than or equal to 0, then automatically determine
>   the number of threads. Otherwise, the size of the underlying
>   threadpool.

So I now specify `-multiThreadGrad 16` on a machine with 8 cores though I don't know if 16 is too many or too few threads.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `--multiThreadGrad 8`.

Example:
 `java -Xmx20g -XX:+UseG1GC -cp /path/to/stanford/ner/jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop /prop/file/name-basic.prop --multiThreadGrad 8`

Also can set the value dynamically using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`

src: [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sequences/SeqClassifierFlags.java#L966)